# Source Generators dependencies not loaded in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, sourcegenerators

I am working on source generator and I have problems with dependencies:

```
It will not contribute to the output and compilation errors may occur as a result. Exception was of type 'FileNotFoundException' with message 'Could not load file or assembly 'Flurl.Http, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

There is a lot of information on how to pack dependencies into nuget, but I reference analyzer project directly like this:

```
<ProjectReference Include="SG.csproj" OutputItemType="Analyzer" ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" />
```

In analyzer project I added `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` and all dependencies are available in output directory, but VS is not using that directory - it uses `AppData\Local\Temp\VBCSCompiler\AnalyzerAssemblyLoader\[...]` instead and it copies only one DLL there.

What can be done to make that work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the way to make it work more or less reliably with some hacks.

Before that I also tried ILMerge, but it didn't work (missing method exceptions).

### Solution:

First of all I embeded dependencies in source generator assembly like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" GeneratePathProperty="true" PrivateAssets="all" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="$(PKGNewtonsoft_Json)\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Visible="false" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Then I created `AssemblyResolve` handler for `AppDomain` (static constructor in generator class) like so:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (_, args) =>
{
    AssemblyName name = new(args.Name);
    Assembly loadedAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetName().FullName == name.FullName);
    if (loadedAssembly != null)
    {
        return loadedAssembly;
    }

    string resourceName = $"Namespace.{name.Name}.dll";

    using Stream resourceStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
    if (resourceStream == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    
    using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    resourceStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

    return Assembly.Load(memoryStream.ToArray());
};
```

Answer (score 7):

The way that this *should* work is outlined in the [source-generators cook-book](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#use-functionality-from-nuget-packages), with their example being:

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild> <!-- Generates a package at build -->
    <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput> <!-- Do not include the generator as a lib dependency -->
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Take a private dependency on Newtonsoft.Json (PrivateAssets=all) Consumers of this generator will not reference it.
         Set GeneratePathProperty=true so we can reference the binaries via the PKGNewtonsoft_Json property -->
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.1" PrivateAssets="all" GeneratePathProperty="true" />

    <!-- Package the generator in the analyzer directory of the nuget package -->
    <None Include="$(OutputPath)\$(AssemblyName).dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Visible="false" />

    <!-- Package the Newtonsoft.Json dependency alongside the generator assembly -->
    <None Include="$(PkgNewtonsoft_Json)\lib\netstandard2.0\*.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Visible="false" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

However, it is my experience that this is still not reliable or robust; this is acknowledged, and I get the impression that improving this experience is part of future planning, but: right now, honestly it is better off simply *not using* dependencies outside of the core framework and the Roslyn libraries that are already loaded. If your dependencies are in the same repo as the analyzer/generator, you might be able to simply suck in the code during build, [for example from here](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/protobuf-net.BuildTools/protobuf-net.BuildTools.csproj#L22):

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- compile what we need from protobuf-net directly; package refs cause pure pain in anaylizers-->
    <Compile Include="../protobuf-net.Core/**/*.cs" Link="protobuf-net.Core"/>
    <Compile Remove="../protobuf-net.Core/obj/**/*.cs" />
    <Compile Include="../protobuf-net.Reflection/**/*.cs"  Link="protobuf-net.Reflection"/>
    <Compile Remove="../protobuf-net.Reflection/obj/**/*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I tried their way, but it seems to work only when analyzer is included as nuget not as a project reference. Unfortunately I want to include external dependencies (Newtonsoft.Json for example) so source code linking wan't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

[`ProjectReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2022#projectreference) is not the same as [`PackageReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files)!

The [GeneratePathProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#generatepathproperty) will not take any action for `ProjectReference` because it is not a package.

So, you just have to add the `TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker` pointing to your local DLL into Source Generator `csproj`.

Example with default output locations:

#### Folder structure

```
- Solution Folder
| - MySolution.sln
| + MyProject
| | - MyProject.csproj
| | + bin
| | | + Debug
| | | | + netstandard2.0
| | | | | - MyProject.dll
| | | + Release
| | | | + netstandard2.0
| | | | | - MyProject.dll
| + MySourceGenerator
| | - MySourceGenerator.csproj
```

#### MySourceGenerator.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>

        <IsRoslynComponent>true</IsRoslynComponent>
        <EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>true</EnforceExtendedAnalyzerRules>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.4" PrivateAssets="all" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.4.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject\MyProject.csproj" PrivateAssets="all"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <GetTargetPathDependsOn>$(GetTargetPathDependsOn);GetDependencyTargetPaths</GetTargetPathDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="GetDependencyTargetPaths">
        <ItemGroup>
            <TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker Include="..\MyProject\bin\$(Configuration)\netstandard2.0\MyProject.dll" IncludeRuntimeDependency="false"/>
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
    
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a definitive answer to this now. The [Source Generator Samples](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/tree/main/samples/CSharp/SourceGenerators/SourceGeneratorSamples) contain an example `.csproj` which has the required setup.

I used this to make a source generator with [Sprache](https://github.com/sprache/Sprache), works great.

Pasting the example `.csproj` here for reference:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="$(MicrosoftNetCompilersToolsetVersion)" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.0.0" PrivateAssets="all" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <!-- Generator dependencies -->
    <PackageReference Include="CsvTextFieldParser" Version="1.2.2-preview" GeneratePathProperty="true" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Handlebars.Net" Version="1.10.1" GeneratePathProperty="true" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.1" GeneratePathProperty="true" PrivateAssets="all" />
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
    <GetTargetPathDependsOn>$(GetTargetPathDependsOn)</GetTargetPathDependsOn>;GetDependencyTargetPaths
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="GetDependencyTargetPaths">
    <ItemGroup>
      <TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker Include="$(PKGCsvTextFieldParser)\lib\netstandard2.0\CsvTextFieldParser.dll" IncludeRuntimeDependency="false" />
      <TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker Include="$(PKGHandlebars_Net)\lib\netstandard2.0\Handlebars.dll" IncludeRuntimeDependency="false" />
      <TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker Include="$(PKGNewtonsoft_Json)\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" IncludeRuntimeDependency="false" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: I still haven't had luck with that. EmbeddedSource workaround is the only solution that works for me.